# How IdentityHashMap v get(key) methods works in these below situation

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.IdentityHashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class IdentityHashMapExample {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        // Created HashMap and IdentityHashMap objects
        Map hashmapObject = new HashMap();

        Map identityObject = new IdentityHashMap();

        // Putting  keys and values in HashMap and IdentityHashMap Object

        hashmapObject.put(new String("key") ,"Google"); 

        hashmapObject.put(new String("key") ,"Facebook"); 

        identityObject.put(new String("identityKey") ,"Google"); 

        identityObject.put(new String("identityKey") ,"Facebook"); 
        // Print HashMap and IdentityHashMap Size : After adding  keys

        System.out.println("HashMap after adding key :"+ hashmapObject);
        System.out.println("Getting value from HashMap :"+ hashmapObject.get("key"));

        System.out.println("IdentityHashMap after adding key :"+ identityObject);
        // why get(key) method return the null value in case of identityHash Map 

        System.out.println("Getting value from IdentityHashMap :" + identityObject.get("identityKey"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to reformat your code - use the preview to check that it's appearing how you expect it to appear - and put your description *outside* the code.

Comment: What did you expect?  `new String("identityKey") != "identityKey"`.

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc of [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) :

> This class implements the Map interface with a hash table, using
>   reference-equality in place of object-equality when comparing keys
>   (and values). In other words, in an IdentityHashMap, two keys k1 and
>   k2 are considered equal if and only if (k1==k2). (In normal Map
>   implementations (like HashMap) two keys k1 and k2 are considered equal
>   if and only if (k1==null ? k2==null : k1.equals(k2)).)

So, if you try to retrieve value using same key reference with which value was inserted, you will get the value. But if you try to get value using difference key reference (even if it is equal), you will get null.

Answer (score 0):

For **IdentityHashMap** keys are compared using the '==' operator whereas in **HashMap** it's done with equals(). 
When you do a new String("key"), it always create a new object in

> heap memory

. On the other hand, if you create object using String literal syntax e.g. "key", it may return an existing object from

> String pool

or create one in pool.
So with equals() both are same as it compares contents but '==' will compare references which will be different in both the cases(hence you are not able to get the object in case of IdentityHashMap).